# How to fetch comments where $comments->post_id = $post->id with Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

Okay,

So I can't figure this one out. 
Eloquent model is new to me.

I'm trying to fetch comments for specific posts.

This is my **post model**:

```
<?php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User'); 
    }

    public function likes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Like');
    }

    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Comment');
    }
}
```

**Comment model:**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Comment extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
    public function post()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Post');
    }
}
```

**Routes:**

```
public function getDashboard(){
        $posts = Post::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get(); // MySQL ORDER BY
        $comments = Comment::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();

        return view('dashboard', ['posts' => $posts], ['comments' => $comments]);
    }
```

($comments might be unnecessary?)

**View:**

```
@foreach($posts as $post)

        <article class="post" data-postid=" {{ $post->id }} ">
            <p>{{ $post->body }}</p>
            <div class="info">
                Posted by {{$post->user->first_name}}  on {{ $post->created_at }}
            </div>
</article>
```

I tried to loop through the comments using:

```
@while($comments->post_id = $post->id)

   <p>{{$comments->body}}</p>

@endwhile
```

I got an error message "Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$body" even though the comments table have a column named "body".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@foreach($post->comments as $comment)
```

Is what you want.  You can use eager loading in the query to speed this up as well:

```
Post::with('comments')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get()
```

Comment: Got it,

I tried a similar thing before using `@foreach($post->comments->body as $comment)`, but that gave me an error message.

Now it works when I use your code and fetch the  body within the foreach loop using

`$comment['body']` 

Thanks!

Comment: Take note at Alexey's answer as well as you could also eager load user to save queries.

Comment: @Devon thanks for your answer. Your answer really helps me lot. It would be very helpful if you give me a solution of this problem. $posts = Post::with('comments:id,body')->get(['id', 'content', 'link']); I am trying to select my desire columns from both tables but it's only return the parent table columns and comments: null

Answer (score 2):

You code with create multiple queries because of `$post->user->first_name`. For example, if you have 70 posts, your code will create 72 query which is awful.

It's much better to use [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) to load posts with comments and users. This code will create just 3 queries:

```
Post::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
    ->with(['user', 'comments' => function ($q) {
        $q->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
    }])->get();
```

And then itarate over collection:

```
@foreach ($posts as $post) {
    <article class="post" data-postid=" {{ $post->id }} ">
    ....
    @foreach ($post->comments as $comment) {
        $comment->content;
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess I'll give you an up for surpassing my detail :)